# Modal box open with strange effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

So i have been working on a modal box that shows on button click, the modal is opennig just fine, but it has a strange effect when openning, it seems that the modal is droping down, while i just want him to fade in.

that's what i'm doing :

```
button_open.onclick = function() {
  $("#myModal").fadeIn(300);
}

AcceptAll.onclick = function() {
  $("#myModal").fadeOut(300);
}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n4gwuv2d/17/)

Can someone help please ?

Comment: looks like there is some issue with .modal CSS. I am trying to debug, can you also make sure by try commenting that behaviour is desired?

Comment: Did you try to use effect attribute of dialogue box like `$( "#dialog" ).dialog({     autoOpen: false,   show: {  effect: "fadein",   duration: 1000}.....`

Comment: your `animation` css is causing this behaviour. Comment this `-webkit-animation-name: animatetop;` whole animation css for `.model-content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change you js code and remove animation effect from your modal-content which is added in you css

```js
button_open.onclick = function() {
  $("#myModal").fadeIn(300);
}

AcceptAll.onclick = function() {
  $("#myModal").fadeOut(300);
}
```

```css
<!--remove this line or comment from .modal-content in your css-->

  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
```

Comment: Care to give the OP some context as to how this piece of code will resolve his issue?

Comment: @Kishan Thank you, that was the solution !

Answer (score 1):

You have a CSS animation

I have created a fiddle from yours to demonstrate the changes needed

https://jsfiddle.net/n4gwuv2d/25/

```
/* Add Animation */
/*
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}
*/
```

and the below in your modal definitions

```
/*animation-name: animatetop;*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add effect on dialogue box initialization similar to below code.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myModal").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "fadeIn",
      duration: 300
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "fadeIn",
      duration: 300
    }
  });

  $("#opener").on("click", function() {
    $("#myModal").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

For more information go to [official site](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)